Tic tac toe game blocking player moves with minimax algorithm implementation
I've implemented the minimax algorithm to this tic tac toe game, and it's working well so far in terms of "Knowing how to win". However, the computer still can't figure out how to prevent me from winning it doesn't see threats that I make it's merely focused on himself winning.
[As an example, here the computer (X) tried to go for the first-row win, I (O) have placed my first move in the center then went for board0][2] cell preventing the computer's win. Now I'm only one move away from winning but the computer instead of blocking my win tried going for the first column win.
Here's the code pen too
In my evaluation function which returns values associated with each move, I've assigned values to threats in an attend to encourage the computer to account for threats as well and block them in result. However, it seems like it didn't work out well.
// 'X' => +10; 'O' => -10; 
function evaluate(board) {
    // evaluating rows;
    for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        if (
            board[i][0] == board[i][1] &&
            board[i][1] == board[i][2]
        ) {
            if (board[i][0] == AI) {
                return +10;
            } else if (board[i][0] == player) {
                return -10;
            }
        };
    };

    // evaluating columns;
    for (let j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        if (
            board[0][j] == board[1][j] &&
            board[1][j] == board[2][j]
        ) {
            if (board[0][j] == AI) {
                return +10;
            } else if (board[0][j] == player) {
                return -10;
            }
        }
    };

    // evaluating the diagonals;
    if (
        board[0][0] == board[1][1] &&
        board[1][1] == board[2][2]
    ) {
        if (board[0][0] == AI) {
            return +10;
        } else if (board[0][0] == player) {
            return -10;
        }
    }
    if (
        board[0][2] == board[1][1] &&
        board[1][1] == board[2][0]
    ) {
        if (board[0][2] == AI) {
            return +10;
        } else if (board[0][2] == player) {
            return -10;
        }
    }

    // detecting row threats;
    for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        if (
            (board[i][0] == player && board[i][1] == player && board[i][2] == '') ||
            (board[i][0] == player && board[i][2] == player && board[i][1] == '') ||
            (board[i][1] == player && board[i][2] == player && board[i][0] == '') 
        ) { return -9; }
    };

    // detection column threats;
    for (let j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        if (
            (board[0][j] == player && board[1][j] == player && board[2][j] == '') ||
            (board[0][j] == player && board[2][j] == player && board[1][j] == '') ||
            (board[1][j] == player && board[2][j] == player && board[0][j] == '')
        ) { return -9; }
    };

    // detecting diagonal threats;
    if ((board[0][0] == player && board[1][1] == player && board[2][2] == '') ||
        (board[0][0] == player && board[2][2] == player && board[1][1] == '') ||
        (board[1][1] == player && board[2][2] == player && board[0][0] == '')
    ) { return -9; };
    if ((board[0][2] == player && board[1][1] == player && board[2][0] == '') ||
        (board[0][2] == player && board[2][0] == player && board[1][1] == '') ||
        (board[1][1] == player && board[2][0] == player && board[0][2] == '')
    ) { return -9; }

    // if none then:
    return 0;
};


Please post the code as text, not a screenshot.

Why is the logic in evaluate() asymmetrical? It seems to me that if a diagonal threat is bad for one side the same must be equally good for the other (so both player and AI should be checked, with the sign of the outcome controlled by which side it is).

I'm sorry to say, but you've not designed this in the right way. You have mixed user-interface concerns with game logic. Please consider starting from scratch, and focus on the game logic alone, based on board and not the cells in your HTML document. For instance, gameOver violates the principle of separation of concern. It's name suggests that it will check whether the game is over, but it does so by looking at the HTML page, not board, and it then calls congratsPlayer. This is bad practice. This is not your question, but I really advise you to start from scratch.
